# Create XML elements from rows

Tags: xml, postgresql

### Background

A table (`equipment_group` [eg]) includes various equipment categories:

```
bakeware
cookware
kitchenware
utensils
```

### Problem

The values must be encoded XML elements, such as:

```
xmlelement( name eg.label )
```

Each element can have multiple objects, as shown in the following XML snippet:

```
<equipment>
  <bakeware>
    <object min-quantity="20">ramekin</object>
    <object alias="pan">shallow baking pan</object>
  </bakeware>
  <cookware>
    <object alias="pot">medium pot</object>
  </cookware>
  <utensils>
    <object alias="torch">kitchen butane torch</object>
    <object alias="sieve">fine-mesh sieve</object>
    <object alias="whisk">wire whisk</object>
  </utensils>
</equipment>
```

### Update

At first glance, it appears as though `xmlconcat` can be used, however `xmlconcat` only allows balanced XML. That is, it does not seem possible to do the following:

```
xmlconcat( '<a>', '<b />', '</a>' )
```

This is well-formed XML, however `xmlconcat` raises an error:

```
ERROR:  invalid XML content
LINE 1: select xmlconcat( '<a>', '<b/>', '</a>' );
                          ^
DETAIL:  Entity: line 1: parser error : Premature end of data in tag a line 1
```

### Question

How would you create XML elements with names that are populated using tabular data?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `xmlconcat` only accepts well-formed XML for parameters, one option is to create a sub-query of the desired elements as follows:

```
  xmlelement( name "bakeware",
    xmlconcat(
      array_to_string( array_agg(
        xmlelement( name "object",
          xmlattributes( e.abridge AS "alias" ),
          e.name
        )
      ), '')::xml
    )
  )
```

This then concatenates all the rows (i.e., every value of `<object ...>`) into a single row of well-formed XML code. The row can then be concatenated using the `xmlconcat` function.

A downside to this solution is that each of the items will have to have a duplicate query with a hardcoded name. This is somewhat acceptable when there are only a few elements. Another downside is that if additional element types are added (e.g., `tableware`, `glassware`, or `dinnerware`) or renamed (e.g., `utensils` to `cutlery`), then source code will have to be modified.